# Regenerate PDF invoices

Tags: magento-1.9, error, invoice, tax, pdf

Dear fellow Magento users,

While filling in my tax report i came to the following conclusion: My tax is inconsistent

My Dashboard shows different total tax then my reports.

Tax Report Image: [image]

Dashboard image : [image]

As you can see, that is roughly a € 10 difference.

Because of that difference i was going to check my taxes manually when i discovered another bug. My PDF invoice is adding random tax to my invoices see images:

Magento in browser invoice: [image] Magento PDF Invoice: (i have highlighted the random tax with a red box)

[image]

At this moment i am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 (recently upgraded)

Is there any way to regenerate the PDF files to check the correctness of my tax in my dashboard/report

Comment: Have you made sure that your dashboard is up to date - by refreshing statistics in the the reports menu in admin ? Looking at the first screenshot it says the stats were last updated back in January - these drive the data in the dashboard - it may not correct your issue but would be worth trying